# Питон, разбитие текста на строки

Tags: python

Прошу помощи, имею вывод, например

```
['Отвертка трещоточная с набором бит (636120)', 'Паста-смывка 200мл (973515-4002)', 'Разрушитель ржавчины (973520-4500)', 'Очиститель тормозов (973520-0650)', 'очки защитные Классик (GL-01010)', 'перчатки (PGT-020)', 'GW40 210мл (973520-3210)']
```

Нужно этот текст превратить в построчный вывод, вот так:

```
Отвертка трещоточная с набором бит (636120)
Паста-смывка 200мл (973515-4002)
Разрушитель ржавчины (973520-4500)
Очиститель тормозов (973520-0650)
очки защитные Классик (GL-01010)
перчатки (PGT-020)
GW40 210мл (973520-3210)
```

Элементов может быть разное количество, которое заведомо неизвестно. Прошу помочь кодом на питоне. Спасибо.

Comment: Какие попытки реализовать это сделали вы? В чем возникли сложности?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вариант без циклов:

```py
d = ['Отвертка трещоточная с набором бит (636120)', 'Паста-смывка 200мл (973515-4002)', 'Разрушитель ржавчины (973520-4500)', 'Очиститель тормозов (973520-0650)', 'очки защитные Классик (GL-01010)', 'перчатки (PGT-020)', 'GW40 210мл (973520-3210)']
print('\n'.join(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = ['Отвертка трещоточная с набором бит (636120)', 'Паста-смывка 200мл (973515-4002)', 'Разрушитель ржавчины (973520-4500)', 'Очиститель тормозов (973520-0650)', 'очки защитные Классик (GL-01010)', 'перчатки (PGT-020)', 'GW40 210мл (973520-3210)']
for a in d:
    print(a)
```

сделано простым перебором списка

Comment: Вашим способом он будет каждую новую строку выводить как отдельное сообщение, а мне нужно, чтобы это было одно сообщение т.к. дальше оно будет отправляться в дискорд